# Filter data on pr_write after hooking

Tags: c++, c, mozilla

I am having troubles filtering data that is passed to PR_Write. It is the Mozilla function that is used in passing all sorts of data sent to the server. I managed to hook it using a DLL( extremely basic ) using the code from Wikipedia on hooking.

The following is the declaration of the PR_Write function referenced from the Mozilla website.

`PRInt32 PR_Write(PRFileDesc *fd, const void *buf, PRInt32 amount);`

The second parameter `buf` is what I am logging by casting it to a `const char*`, it works fine but I don't know how I can filter the data since it logs everything from start to end.

The code below is what I tried but it is too heavy a loop and crashes Mozilla.

```
char *p=(char*)buf; // get pointer to beginning of the buffer
while (*p!='\00')
{
    // do some data filtering

    *p++;
}
```

The idea was from Grayhat Python book to iterate through the buffer and filter data as needed but the loop is too much since the buffer is always extremely large.

Overall, I need a way to filter the data that is passed to the second parameter.

Thanks for any suggestions in advance :)

Comment: Why are you assuming the buffer is a NUL-terminated character string?

Comment: got the idea from Grayhat Python..

Comment: Having read the Grayhat Python book I see they are assuming this is a NUL terminated string however tryign to get the examples to run recently https://github.com/stavinski/grayhat_python_redux this is no longer the case so you must use the amount parameter to determine length of the buffer.